# How to declare class using generics types - Java 1.7

Tags: java, generics

I have following class:

```
public class AClass<T extends XYZClass> extends BFunction<DTOClass, T>{
    @Override
    public <T extends XYZClass> T apply(DTOClass input) {
        return null;
    } 
}
```

where T is generic Type, BFunction is function that implements com.google.common.base.Function with apply method. The problem is that this class declaration construction is invalid, because it corresponds following apply method:

```
@Override
public T apply(DTOClass input) {
    return null;
}
```

I also tried:

```
public class AClass extends BFunction<DTOClass, <T extends XYZClass> T>{
    @Override
    public <T extends XYZClass> T apply(DTOClass input) {
            return null;
    }
}
```

but this syntax is invalid.
Could you advise me how to correct my class declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring a [generic method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) in your parent class, where the `<T extends XYZClass>` clause has nothing to do with the `<T extends XYZClass>` in your class declaration.

What you likely want to do is remove `<T extends XYZClass>` from your method declaration and overrides altogether.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the type variable declared on the method:

```
public class AClass<T extends XYZClass> extends BFunction<DTOClass, T>{
    @Override
    public /* remove this */ T apply(DTOClass input) {
        return null;
    } 
}
```

You're trying to declare another type variable called `T` which hides the type variable declared on the class.